# Reference for result and proof that $R(g\circ f)\cong Rg\circ Rf$ for morphisms of ringed spaces $X\xrightarrow{f}Y\xrightarrow{g}Z$

Tags: reference-request, sheaf-cohomology, derived-functors

I am trying to find a reference that states and proves the following Lemma:

> **Lemma.** Let $(X,\mathcal{O}_X)\xrightarrow{f}(Y,\mathcal{O}_Y)\xrightarrow{g}(Z,\mathcal{O}_Z)$ be morphisms of ringed spaces. Then $R(g\circ f)\cong Rg\circ Rf$.

A proof is given by application of [015M](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/09NU): if $\mathcal{I}$ is an injective $\mathcal{O}_X$-module, then $\mathcal{I}$ is flasque ([09SX](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/09SX)), so $f_*\mathcal{I}$ is flasque too; thus, $f_*\mathcal{I}$ is acyclic ([09SY](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/09SY)).

I haven't found the result's statement on the Stacks Project (I have only checked on the [Cohomology of Sheaves](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01DW) chapter), and I haven't found it either on Hartshorne's or Vakil's.